# How to create a landing page after adding a product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So i'm working with WordPress and WooCommerce for a website and i have a task that i don't know how to solve. When i create a WooCommerce product i need another landing page for that product to be created automatically where i can see details of the product and similar products.

I was trying to use `wp_insert_post()` but i can't figure it out how to add the page after adding a product

Is there a way i can do that or is there a plugin that gives you the function to do that?

I hope i was clear in the question.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the WordPress save_post action: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

On saving a post, check if the post type is Woocommerce's product post type. If true, you can do whatever you want :)

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful